# How to access data from C function called from python using Ctypes module

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, windows, ctypes

I am trying to get data out of a non returning C function call made from ctypes library back to python.

The C stack gets input from func A(), calls func B() for processing and calls func C() for sending output via hardware (eg UART).

I am calling func A() from python using ctypes library. The func C is currently a wrapper code which prints data to console. This works fine but I have a GUI(PyQt5) on which I would like to show this data ( a string) .

I am currently using StdOut Redirection as per this article. https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/
But stdout redirection is not working well for me, some of the outputs are still going to stdout and stops working after some outputs.

This is what I am currently using.

Cfile.c:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdint.h"
void test_consoleout()
{
    fprintf(stdout,"0xDE,0xAD,0xBE,0xEF\n");
    fflush(stdout);
}
```

Pythonfile.py

```
from ctypes import *
import ctypes.util
import time, sys, threading, os, io, tempfile
from contextlib import contextmanager
import platform

if platform.system() == "Linux":
    libc = ctypes.CDLL(None)
    c_stdout = ctypes.c_void_p.in_dll(libc, 'stdout')
if platform.system() == "Windows":
    class FILE(ctypes.Structure):
        _fields_ = [
            ("_ptr", c_char_p),
            ("_cnt", c_int),
            ("_base", c_char_p),
            ("_flag", c_int),
            ("_file", c_int),
            ("_charbuf", c_int),
            ("_bufsize", c_int),
            ("_tmpfname", c_char_p),
        ]

    ucrtbase = CDLL("ucrtbase")
    libc = ucrtbase
    iob_func = ucrtbase.__acrt_iob_func
    iob_func.restype = c_void_p
    iob_func.argtypes = [c_int]
    s_stdin = iob_func(0)
    c_stdout = iob_func(1)

@contextmanager
def stdout_redirector(stream):
    # The original fd stdout points to. Usually 1 on POSIX systems.
    original_stdout_fd = sys.stdout.fileno()

    def _redirect_stdout(to_fd):
        """Redirect stdout to the given file descriptor."""
        # Flush the C-level buffer stdout
        libc.fflush(c_stdout)
        # Flush and close sys.stdout - also closes the file descriptor (fd)
        sys.stdout.close()
        # Make original_stdout_fd point to the same file as to_fd
        os.dup2(to_fd, original_stdout_fd)
        # Create a new sys.stdout that points to the redirected fd
        sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(os.fdopen(original_stdout_fd, 'wb'))

    # Save a copy of the original stdout fd in saved_stdout_fd
    saved_stdout_fd = os.dup(original_stdout_fd)
    try:
        # Create a temporary file and redirect stdout to it
        tfile = tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='w+b')
        _redirect_stdout(tfile.fileno())
        # Yield to caller, then redirect stdout back to the saved fd
        yield
        _redirect_stdout(saved_stdout_fd)
        # Copy contents of temporary file to the given stream
        tfile.flush()
        tfile.seek(0, io.SEEK_SET)
        stream.write(tfile.read())
    finally:
        tfile.close()
        os.close(saved_stdout_fd)

C_STACK = CDLL(".\CStack.dll")

while(True):  
    f = io.BytesIO()    
    with stdout_redirector(f):
        C_STACK .test_consoleout()
    time.sleep(0.05)
    print('Got stdout: "{0}"'.format(f.getvalue()))
```

Is this recommended?  Is there a better method (reliable and minimum overhead)?. I am using windows.

Comment: So you can control the C code?  If so, you can certainly just write to some global variable and have Python examine it after the call returns.

Comment: I can only modify func C to write to a global variable. The func A does not return the data available at func C to the python call. How can we can write to a global variable in C code which can be accessed form python? I didnt know if this was possible.

Comment: Where is the *FILE* structure used?

Comment: @ayushc: It’s simpler than calling functions, of course, so it’s easily overlooked, but [`ctypes` supports it](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#accessing-values-exported-from-dlls).  (Or you could add another function that returned data from the global.)